# How to set custom domain name for nodejs app hosting on azure linux VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am hosting my nodejs project on microsoft azure. Now i wanted do custom domain but i don't know how to do, I have external go daddy domain.

Presently my project running on azure vm's default DNSName.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com domain, now I wanted to change my goDaddy domain. How can I do that, Can anyone help to do this

below is my vm's configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we can add **A record** to map your domain name to this VM's public IP address, or you can add **CNAME** to map your domian name to this VM's DNSName.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com.

About add an A record.
[image]

More information about add a record, **strong text**please refer to this [link](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238).

Comment: Azure is not the domain registrar, so you can't buy domain name from azure. as you mentioned, you have a domain name from go daddy, we can use this domain name.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance. If it helps, please mark it as an answer, thanks.