# How can we buy Domain name for VM on Azure which is running NodeJs App

Tags: node.js, azure

I have deployed my nodejs project on azure linux VM, currently it is running on default host name " DNSName.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com".

Now I wanted to run on new domain name, How can I buy new domain for the virtual Machine?

Please suggest me, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can buy the domain name from a domain name service. Then you can link it to azure.

Comment: I had answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872094/how-to-set-custom-domain-name-for-nodejs-app-hosting-on-azure-linux-vm Please check it

Comment: @json, Sir i dont want third party domain. We can buy domain Azure itself, how to do that? third party integration i got after looking into your post.

Comment: @Chandrashekhar Azure  is not the domain registrar, so we can't do it with azure.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I buy new domain for the virtual Machine?

Sorry, I misunderstand your meaning. If you want to buy domain name like this, we can via Azure Portal to buy it. (**this just work for web app, we still can't buy domain name for Azure VM**)
[image]

Custom domain names are **not** enabled for Free tier, **you must scale up to a higher pricing tier**, so that you can buy domain name from Azure Portal.   [image]

Comment: Sir but there is buy domain option while deploying website in azure as app service.

Comment: Just look into this sir, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app

Comment: @Chandrashekhar  buy domain option just work for web app, we can't buy domain name for Azure VM.

Comment: Ok thank you sir, so now only way to do is, redirecting go daddy domain in azure.

Comment: @Chandrashekhar  If it helps, please don't forget to accept it, we can follow this link to mark it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow